# Airplay mirroring app screen out of the app

Tags: ios, airplay

Can I launch AirPlay from my custom app and then display the custom app screen on the external monitor? I found a solution to display videos.

```
    
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            AVRoutePickerView *routerPickerView = [[AVRoutePickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
            routerPickerView.activeTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            routerPickerView.delegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview:routerPickerView];
            
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:routerPickerView.bounds];
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Zubehoer.jpg"];
            [routerPickerView addSubview:imageView];
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        
   
    
        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"]];
    
   
       AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
       AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
       AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
       [playerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 40.0f)];
       [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
       [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
       [player play];
    
    
    


    
    
}
```

But is it also possible to mirror the screen from within the app?